# What is the proper way of adding a "show user location" button for an MKMapView in SwiftUI?

Tags: mkmapview, swiftui

I'm trying to create a SwiftUI view with an MKMapView and a button to navigate to the user location. Below is the entirety of my code. I created a view called `MapView` which is conforms to `UIViewRepresentable` to hold my MKMapView. I have a location button that, on tapping, sets `shouldNavigateToUserLocation` to true. This causes the UI to reload, and my `MapView` navigates to the user location if `shouldNavigateToUserLocation` is true. Then, it sets `shouldNavigateToUserLocation` to false, so that the MapView is not constantly moving to the user location on ever state change.

This approach seems to work when running on real devices, but I get the warning "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior." on line 87, which is `shouldNavigateToUserLocation = false`. This is understandable, but my question is, how can I avoid this? I can't seem to find a way to restructure my code so I'm not violating the rule of not modifying state during a view update, while still having the map navigate to the user location when and only when the user presses the button.

I have tried a couple of different approaches, but I mainly get stuck with the problem of neither my MapView nor my Controller class actually having direct access to the MKMapView. I understand why that is in SwiftUI, but it really limits what I can do.

Here is the entirety of my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {

  @State var currentlyDisplayingLocationAuthorizationRequest = false
  @State var shouldNavigateToUserLocation = false

  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      MapView(currentlyDisplayingLocationAuthorizationRequest: $currentlyDisplayingLocationAuthorizationRequest,
              shouldNavigateToUserLocation: $shouldNavigateToUserLocation)

      HStack {
        Spacer()
        VStack {
          Spacer()
          Button(action: {
            self.checkForLocationAuthorizationAndNavigateToUserLocation()
          }) {
            Image(systemName: "location")
              .imageScale(.large)
              .accessibility(label: Text("Locate Me"))
              .padding()
          }
          .background(Color.gray)
          .cornerRadius(10)
          .padding()
        }
      }
    }
    .onAppear {
      self.shouldNavigateToUserLocation = true
    }
  }

  func checkForLocationAuthorizationAndNavigateToUserLocation() {
    currentlyDisplayingLocationAuthorizationRequest = false

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
      print("location authorization not determined")
      currentlyDisplayingLocationAuthorizationRequest = true
      locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
      return
    }

    shouldNavigateToUserLocation = true
  }

}

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

  @Binding var currentlyDisplayingLocationAuthorizationRequest: Bool
  @Binding var shouldNavigateToUserLocation: Bool

  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
    let map = MKMapView()
    map.delegate = context.coordinator
    map.showsUserLocation = true
    return map
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    if !currentlyDisplayingLocationAuthorizationRequest && shouldNavigateToUserLocation {
      moveToUserLocation(map: uiView)
    }
  }

  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }

  // MARK: Location -

  private func moveToUserLocation(map: MKMapView) {
    guard let location = locationManager.location else { return }

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate,
                                    span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02,
                                                           longitudeDelta: 0.02))
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    shouldNavigateToUserLocation = false
  }

  // MARK: Coordinator -

  final class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {

    var control: MapView

    init(_ control: MapView) {
      self.control = control
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I answered the question in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398437/how-to-add-a-move-back-to-user-location-button-in-swiftui/67956924#67956924, or you can refer to my demo project in my github: https://github.com/zhihuitang/UserLocationDemo

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you are searching for, but you should take a look at [my recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59294036/10967642) to another related question ([How to add a move back to user location button in swiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58398437/10967642)). I think it can help you, or others if they are facing the same problem.